# Node JS code not running in order

Tags: sql, node.js, azure

I have no idea why the code do not run as I expected.
When the UserExist is called, it should either console.log one of the statements that I set in my function code.
But the result is like the following the picture. Apreciate that if somebody can help!!
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EznIT.jpg)

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var config = require('./configuration/sqlconfig');

var Username = "Testing";

sql.connect(config);
console.log("Connected to DB");


if (!UserExist(Username)) {
    InsertNewRecord(Username);
}


function isEmptyObject(obj) {
    return !Object.keys(obj).length;
}

// This should work both there and elsewhere.
function isEmptyObject(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function UserExist(Username) { 
        console.log('Checking whether user exists or not... ');
        new sql.Request().query("SELECT * FROM dbo.DB_Users WHERE Username =     '" + Username + "';")
        .then(function (recordset) {
            if (isEmptyObject(recordset)) {
                console.log("The User does not exist, ready to insert");
                return true;
            } else {
                console.log("The user is existed already.");
                return false;
            }
        }).catch(function (err) {
            //When errors come      
        });
}



function InsertNewRecord(Username) {
    console.log('Attempting to Insert records...');
    new sql.Request().query("INSERT INTO dbo.Embright_Users (Username) VALUES ('" + Username + "');");
    console.log("Added one new record");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callbacks are not chained correctly. The InsertNewRecord() should be passed as callback to UserExist() function to make sure the execute in sequence. eg:

```
// Calling UserExist with a callback instead of 'if' statement
UserExist(Username, InsertNewRecord)

function UserExist(Username, callback) {
    console.log('Checking whether user exists or not... ');
    new sql.Request().query("SELECT * FROM dbo.DB_Users WHERE Username =     '" + Username + "';")
    .then(function (recordset) {
        if (isEmptyObject(recordset)) {
            console.log("The User does not exist, ready to insert");
            // Calling InsertNewRecord with the username passed
            callback(Username);
        } else {
            console.log("The user is existed already.");
           // Do nothing
        }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        //When errors come   
    });
}
```

Comment: But what if I have different parameters for insertnewuser?

Comment: If you have different parameters to pass to a callback, there are different ways you could do this, but the important thing is to encapuslate the params and logic within the callback function and let the callback do its own job of fetching the other params. eg: func2(params, callback) { //Does something and calls func1(params) };  func1(params, callback) {//Uses params and fetches params2 } ; Consider using a library like async (http://caolan.github.io/async/) - will help you organize the code better.